# Нужна функция, меняющая задний фон div каждые 500 мс. Требуется устранение ошибки

Tags: javascript

У меня что-то не так. Функция `color()` должна вызывать саму себя каждые 500 мс и менять задний фон тега `div` с классом `.text`

Код:

```js
const text = document.querySelector('.text');

text.style.background = 'red';
text.style.width = '200px';
text.style.height = '200px';

function color () {
    const text = document.querySelector('.text');
    if (text.style.background == 'blue') {
        text.style.background = 'red';
    } else if (text.style.background == 'red') {
        text.style.background = 'green';
    } else {
        text.style.background = 'blue';
    }
    setInterval(() => {
        color();
    }, 500);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="text"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: достаточно, сет интервал вынести  за пределы функции

Answer (score 2):

В вашем текущем коде нужно вместо

```
setInterval
```

написать

```
setTimeout
```

Всё потому что `setInterval` вызывается бесконечно и будет бесконечно запускать функцию каждые 500 мс. При каждом новом вызове будет происходить запуск всё нового и нового счётчика `setInterval`, в итоге их будет огромное количество и будет происходить наслаиваение друг на друга всё большего количества бесконечных `setInterval`. А `setTimeout` отрабатывает только один раз. Таймаут вызывал функцию и "умер". В следующий вызов функции будет вызов нового таймаута, который отработает тоже один раз и тоже после срабатываения "умрёт"

Ну и не забыть самый первый вызов `color()` тоже надо

Comment: В вопросе не то имелось ввиду. Как раз вопрос по то, что бы менять цвет каждые 500мс. А если просто вызвать функцию color(), не меняя ее, то каждый ее вызов будет порождать новый таймер. после второго прохода их будет 4, затем 8, 16... и собственно через некоторое время все "зависнет"

Comment: @SwaD Вы мой ответ читали? А код с учётом моего ответа запускали? Вот запустите и увидете, что вы не правы

Comment: @SwaD а вот ваш ответ как раз совершенно неправильный. Потому что функция в итоге не вызывает саму себя

Comment: Справедливое замечание! Обновите ваш ответ, добавив вариант реализации. Из ответа не очень понятно, что куда надо добавить и что именно изменить.

Comment: @SwaD вот скажите, почему вы считаете, что фразу "Нужно вместо

`setInterval`

написать

`setTimeout`"  можно понять двояко? С учётом того, что в коде есть **только одно место** где это слово встречается

Comment: Ну вот я же смог так прочитать, а начинающий может вообще не разобраться. Если в ваш ответ вставите пример реализации, он будет более полезен для того, кто обратился, а может и для других посетителей.